# relative mouse position not working properly in ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, ctypes

I would like to make the mouse move to relative coordinates, but the mouse is oscillating at the x and y position.

```
class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_long),
                ("y", ctypes.c_long)]
        
def position(x=None, y=None):
    cursor = POINT()
        ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(cursor))
        return (x if x else cursor.x, y if y else cursor.y)

@_genericPyDirectInputChecks
def moveTo(x=None, y=None, duration=None, tween=None, logScreenshot=False, _pause=True, relative=False):
    if not relative:
        x, y = position(x, y) 
        x, y = _to_windows_coordinates(x, y)
        extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
        ii_ = Input_I()
        ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, (MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE), 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
        command = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(0), ii_)
        SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(command), ctypes.sizeof(command))
    else:
        currentX, currentY = position()
        print(currentX)
        print(x-currentX)
        moveRel(x - currentX, y - currentY, relative=True)

@_genericPyDirectInputChecks
def moveRel(xOffset=None, yOffset=None, duration=None, tween=None, logScreenshot=False, _pause=True, relative=False):
    if not relative:
        x, y = position()
        if xOffset is None:
            xOffset = 0
        if yOffset is None:
            yOffset = 0
        moveTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)
    else:
        extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
        ii_ = Input_I()
        ii_.mi = MouseInput(xOffset, yOffset, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
        command = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(0), ii_)
        SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(command), ctypes.sizeof(command))
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] including all imports and definitions to reproduce the problem without edits.

Answer (score 0):

My guess without a reproducible example the following since `x` and `y` could be zero and would be considered false:

```
def position(x=None, y=None):
    cursor = POINT()
    ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(cursor))
    return (x if x is not None else cursor.x, y if y is not None else cursor.y)
```